# prove of $(x^{2}-y^{2}) z^{'}_{x}+xyz^{'}_{y}=xyz$ where $z$ is..

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I get some doubts about how to prove the following expression:

$$(x^{2}-y^{2}) z^{'}_{x}+xyz^{'}_{y}=xyz$$

where z is:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
z=& e^{y}f(& ye^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}} }) 
\end{array}$$

My doubts arise when representing the derivatives of z with respect to x, y and their respective internal derivative, I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

They are partial derivatives simply, but you have to consider the chain rule for the derivative of the single variable function $f\to f'=\dfrac{df(v)}{dv}$ So, for the partial wrt $x$, first differentiate wrt the argument $v$ and multiply by the partial wrt $x$ of the argument. Here, $v=ye^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}$

$z_x=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=e^yf'(v)(x/y)e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}$

$z_y=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=e^yf(v)+e^yf'(v)(e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}-e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}(x^2/y^2))=$

$=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=e^yf(v)+e^yf'(v)e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}(1-(x^2/y^2))=$

For the first term;

$(x^2-y^2)z_x=(x^2-y^2)e^yf'(v)e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}(x/y)=$

$=e^yf'(v)e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}(x^2(x/y)-y^2(x/y))=e^yf'(v)e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}(x^3/y-xy)$

For the second,

$xyz_y=xy\left(e^yf(v)+e^yf'(v)e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}\left(1-(x^2/y^2)\right)\right)=$

$=xye^yf(v)+e^yf'(v)e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}\left(xy-xy(x^2/y^2)\right)=$

$=xyz+e^yf'(v)e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}\left(xy-x^3/y\right)$

Finally

$(x^2-y^2)z_x+xyz_y=xyz+e^yf'(v)e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}(x^3/y-xy)+e^yf'(v)e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2y^{2}}}\left(xy-x^3/y\right)=xyz$